# Summary Links WebPart

Tags: 2013, web-part, links

Is there a Summary Links WebPart in SharePoint 2013? I have the `Publishing Feature Activated` but can only see the `'Links'` and `'Promoted Links'` webparts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If publishing feature is activated on the site collection level then you can see the `Summary Link Web Part`. it is available in the Office 365 as well but not in foundation.

here is the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a *Summary Links* web part in SharePoint 2013. It can be found under *Content Rollup*.

However, it is not available to SharePoint Foundation, just versions above.